# Prevent a form from Submitting preventDefault issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to stop my form from submitting by doing the following but it is continuing to submit when I hit the submit button:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    //When the form is submitted do this...
    $("#stripe-payment-form").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); 
        // disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks
        $('#stripe-submit').attr("disabled", "disabled");
        // send the card details to Stripe
        Stripe.createToken({
            number: $('.card-number').val(),
            cvc: $('.card-cvc').val(),
            exp_month: $('.card-expiry-month').val(),
            exp_year: $('.card-expiry-year').val()
        }, stripeResponseHandler);
        // prevent the form from submitting with the default action
        return false;
    });
});
```

Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: What's this? `function($)`

Comment: Any other element with the same `id` on the page?

Comment: You can either use `preventDefault()` or `return false`. You don't need both.

Comment: Can you replicate the error in a jsfiddle?

Comment: No, the only element on the page with that `id` is the form.

Comment: Is the `form` added to the page dynamically?

Comment: When changing the `disabled` property, use `.prop('disabled', flag)` instead of `.attr()`.

Comment: Is any javascript error in console?

Comment: Please check the console (dev tools) for possible JavaScript errors.

Comment: Depending your jq version, consider instead to use `$('#stripe-submit').prop("disabled", true);`

Answer (score -1):

Try to prevent submitting the form from the "submit" button itself:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //When the form is submitted do this...
    $("#stripe-submit").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); 
        // disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks
        $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
        // send the card details to Stripe
        Stripe.createToken({
            number: $('.card-number').val(),
            cvc: $('.card-cvc').val(),
            exp_month: $('.card-expiry-month').val(),
            exp_year: $('.card-expiry-year').val()
        }, stripeResponseHandler);
        // prevent the form from submitting with the default action
        return false;
    });
});
```

Also, make sure you correct your first line from:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
```

To:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

...as pointed out by A. Wolff :)

Comment: Why passing `$` as function parameter when obviously `$` already refers to jQuery? ;)

Comment: @A.Wolff Nice observation! I missed that -and also corrected the code! Thanx!

Comment: makes no sense to bind to button, what if user uses keyboard to submit

Comment: @charlietfl Can you please use your keyboard to submit this form -> http://jsfiddle.net/qd3zpde3/2/ ...The "enter" button doesn't work -not for me at least- unless I'm missing something...

Comment: submits fine for me when fields have data and hit enter. Completely bypasses click handler

Comment: @charlietfl if you fill out your fields, it will surely submit, since that's what the function requires in my example... However, this form will never submit with keyboard -nor click: http://jsfiddle.net/sbhtz02w/1/ (even though I bind to the button!)... The point that I am trying to make here is that you were not right when you wrote: "makes no sense to bind to button, what if user uses keyboard to submit" ...unless -again- I am missing something!

Comment: but OP wants to use Stripe API to submit . The API makes asynchronous call to get token first, then submits form within callback. Won't work using your approach if user hits enter

Comment: I can't see how it won't work... After the "e.preventDefault()" you can do anything you like -not just a simple alert like I did in the fiddle... One can make an ajax call, make an async call to Stripe... All these can be triggered either by click or by pressing enter... I just can't understand how a press of an "enter" would act differently than a "click"... If by any chance you can show me a piece of code as an example, I might be able to follow you...